# Can you configure default settings for the XmlWriter used by WCF?

Tags: wcf, xmlwriter

Is there any way to configure the default XmlWriter used by WCF service with DataContractSerializer when serializing data?

Out of the box WCF service using DataContractSerializer is losing the new lines (\r\n).

**[Edit:** I apologize for the confusion. Out of the box WCF DOES NOT lose the new lines.**]**

I am able to make XmlWriter  encode the new lines to `&#xD;` by using  XmlWriterSettings (NewLineHandling.Entitize), but I want to make WCF behave the same way when serialize my object.

```
public string Serialize<T>(T object)
  {
     var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
     using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
     {
       var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize };
       using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
       {
          serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, object);
          string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
          return xml;
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different `XmlWriter`, you'll need to use a custom message encoder. The sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx shows how you could write one.

But I've never seen WCF losing the `\r\n` characters - it properly entitizes the `\r` into `&#XD;`, at least all the times I checked. When I run the code below it shows the characters properly returned:

```
public class StackOverflow_12205872
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        string str = proxy.Echo("Hello\r\nworld");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(str[5] == '\r' && str[6] == '\n');

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

And Fiddler shows this request being sent:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header></s:Header><s:Body><Echo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><text>Hello&#xD;
world</text></Echo></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

The response also contains the entitized CR character. Can you share more details about your configuration (including binding)?